# Convert structured text file into CSV

Tags: python, string, split

How to achieve below output in python :

Input:

```
Prataps Peter A         A    T         9945.03  
Shailin Amy             B              9437.50
```

Output:

```
Prataps,Peter,A,A,T,9945.03  
Shailin,Amy,,B,,9437.50
```

Code i am using :

```
    input = "C:\Apps\Data\Report\CC_report.csv"
    final = "C:\Apps\Data\Report\CC_report1.csv"
    header = "LastName,FirstName,Middle_Name ,ST,B1,CURRENT_BALANCE)
    with open(input) as oldfile, open(final, 'w') as newfile:
        newfile.write(header+"\n")
        for line in oldfile:
           line1 = re.sub(" +", ",", line.strip())
           newfile.write(line1 + "\n")
```

Comment: no need, just use bash
`$ sed -i 's/ /,/g' filename.txt > filename.csv`

Comment: is there a reason you want to do this in python? if you're brave you can run input.replace(" ", ",")

Comment: How many values each row should have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Numpy to define the column width . Data needs to be cleansed and defined before processing the file.

```
    #source file location  
    path = "myfile.csv"  
    # define column location and then define the width   
    column_locations = np.array([1, 25, 30, 31, 47, 58, 75, 92, 109, 126, 132, 152, 158, 163, 179, 190, 207, 224, 241, 258, 264, 295, 311, 322, 356, 373 ])  
    widths = column_locations[1:] - column_locations[:-1]  

    #creating numpy array from the source file   
    data = np.genfromtxt(path, dtype=None, delimiter=widths, autostrip=True)
    print(data)  
    data =np.char.replace(data,',',' ')  
    np.savetxt(path,data,delimiter=",",fmt='%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the input given, I can see that fields are separated by space, so you will have to replace them by a comma

```
file = open('data.txt', 'r')
data=myfile.read().replace(' ', ',')
```

Once the content is retrieved you can append it to a new file

```
new_file = open("data.csv", "w")
new_file.write(data)
new_file.close()
```

Comment: I need to replace the white spaces but  need consider the missing values as well .Edit my question you will see that it is structured file

Comment: If there are missing values it means that the value of the field is empty. You have to let it like that. By the way it seems that the file is not really structured because in a structured file all the rows should not have empty fields

Comment: In the second row ,values are not there for column 3& 5 so the output should have the empty commas .

Comment: I think you want to store only the rows that don't have any empty fields right ?

Comment: Apologies if i am not able to explain the scenario .I pasted my code in the question  which is replacing all the consecutive white spaces with comma . But I want that if the value is missing (e.g second row middle name is not there ) output should be like  column1, column2,,coulmn4

Comment: I see, but this is not what should be done. For example it doesn't make any sense to replace the last name by the first name just because the last name is empty. This way data will not be correct. I guess its better to just let them empty, just like they were.

Comment: If i replace every consecutive white space then it will corrupt the data and will never match with header .  
  LastName, FirstName, Middle_Name, ST, B1, CURRENT_BALANCE  
        need this   
        Shailin, Amy, ,B,, 9437.50  
        not this  
        Shailin, Amy, B, 9437.50